# How to get CGAffineTransform from two CGSizes?

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

Suppose, I have two CGSize named A and B.

Where

```
B = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(A, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x,y));
```

Now how to calculate x and y if I know A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale factor for transforming one size to another is simply dividing the target dimension with the current dimension. That means `x=B.width/A.width` same for height.

Though it is not clear from the question if this is what you wanted, so the solution might as well be `x=y=42`.